# error getting while inserting multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

my table

```
CREATE TABLE emp(
   EMP_NO NUMBER, 
   EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
   ADDRESS VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
   PH_NO NUMBER(10,0), 
   DPT_NO NUMBER
)
```

inserting query:

```
insert into emp (
    emp_no,
    emp_name,
    address,
    ph_no,
    dpt_no) 
  values (100,'mohan','hyd',7569936347,101),
         (101,'ram','ctr',9553438342,102);
```

In this manner i write insert query for multiple records inserting purpose...but i'm getting error as "sql command is not perperly ended.i don't know how to rwsolve this one one..any can help me

Comment: which DBMS do you use? which language/library do you use to access your database?

Comment: i'm using sql.it doesn't work above mentioned query.why?

Comment: oracle sql developer am using but am not getting desire out put.please help me any one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using sql server prior to 2008. You cannot use this syntax to separate the rows. You could write different insert commands or use a select statement using union to force them into one insert command.

EDIT: Since you are using oracle see if [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/insert_rows.php) is helpful.